# JavaScript - Polymer: this.splice after paper-alert-dialog

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, dialog, polymer

I'm trying to add a paper-alert-dialog when deleting an item from the array, but I cannot seem to understand how this works.

I have the following function that works now, without the dialog:

```
_delete(e) {
          var index = this.todos.indexOf(e.model.item);
          this.splice('todos', index, 1)
          this.$.grid.clearCache();
          }
```

if I set this function to fire on-tap, it works like a charm, but I am trying to add a confirmation dialog. So, I made a new function that first calls the alert dialog:

```
_confdel() {
this.$.Delconfirm.open();
}
```

If I set the paper-button on-confirm="_delete()" this won't work.
It will trigger the alert-dialog, but paper-dialog on-confirm won't delete the entry when it fires _delete.

What am I doing wrong here?

Plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/UXNhfLU4DrDkBdpeIkuQ?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of calling `on-confirm="_delete()"` you have to only tell the name of the function like: `on-confirm="_delete"`.

I assume your `confirm-dialog` and `_delete` function are in the same element si it can call `this._delete`

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your reply. Here is a plunkr so you can understand what I'm trying to say, I know I didn't explain well... https://plnkr.co/edit/UXNhfLU4DrDkBdpeIkuQ?p=preview

Comment: could you please also add your html ? without it I am unable to solve anything. And have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late reply. Sure! Here's the plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/UXNhfLU4DrDkBdpeIkuQ?p=info . Thank you!

Comment: @unkn0wnx everything should be ok. I just tried `paper-alert-dialog` and i had no problem. Even with the same flow as you have. Try to simplify your code as much as possible so only necessary functions and html remains. Try to find out where is the problem. Try to reinstall element to newest version (if you are using Polymer version at least 1.9.x)

Comment: It still doesn't work on my side. When I press delete the dialog opens, but when I try to delete the entry it gives me an error:  cannot read property 'item' of undefined.

Comment: I have managed to make it work after removing e.model.item from var index = this.todos.indexOf(e.model.item); Thanks a lot for you replies. Where can I read more about this reference so I can understand what it does? I still don't understand e.modal.item's purpose or what it does in my code.

Comment: oh man... First rule of aquestions.. check if there are some errors and post them with the question. If you had error `'item' of undefined` it's so obvious that your code won't work.. oh my god... Since you removed your code from plunkr I can't help you more. But `e.model` is event passed in function as first parameter when you have `on-click` on some element.